# Proof of derivative of convolution $(h * f)' = h' * f$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, convolution

I am writing an article related to Computer Vision but to complete the math under the technique I should prove the following equality:

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(h*f) = \left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}h \right)*f$$

I am not a mathematician and I am not used to convolution analysis. So, how can I prove it?

Comment: You can start with the definition of convolution.

Comment: X-posted: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/61627/21075

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that the convolution is defined as
$$(h\ast f)(x) = \int_{-∞}^∞ h(x - τ)f(τ) \mathrm d τ \quad \text{for $x ∈ ℝ$}.$$
Now use the special case of [Leibniz’s integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

To apply this, you only need $h$ to be continuously differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d x}(h*f) &= \frac{d}{d x}\int f(t)h(x-t)dt\\
&= \int \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(f(t)h(x-t)\right)dt \\
&= \int f(t)\frac{\partial h(x-t)}{\partial x}dt \\
&= \left(\frac{d}{d x}h\right)*f
\end{align}

Comment: The step from the first to the second line is very much nontrivial